# Do chickens not lay eggs in cold biomes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing Skyblock and I found a chicken in my mob spawner. I have set up a basic chicken farm in an Ice Biomes biome, and every so often I run by and see if there are any eggs the chicken has laid. I know chickens take a while to lay eggs (and I haven't left the chunk), but a while has gone by and there are no eggs from the chicken, is the biome too cold?

Comment: It's going to take a long time to build up a useful chicken farm starting from just one chicken. It is probably worth your time to see if you can round up a handful more. At least, say, 6 or 7.

Comment: I'm trying to, but I'm playing Skyblock and the chicken spawned in my mob spawner and fell down, at which point I put him in a hole. I would round up more if there were both more chickens nearby and I had a seed.

Comment: If it spawned in your mob spawner, it's likely from a chicken jockey, and as nelson2tm and Sira point out in their answers, will never lay an egg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chickens should lay eggs in every biome. They do not lay eggs if:

- They are baby
- They are or were part of a Chicken Jockey
- The chunk the chicken in is unloaded
- If you're playing single player and the game is paused

Also, make sure the item didn't despawn. Items despawn after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

They do lay eggs in cold biomes, it doesn't matter where they are, just make sure they are not a baby (chick) or a part of a chicken jockey.

Answer (score 1):

It takes 5 - 10 minutes (6000 - 12000 ticks [There are 20 ticks in 1 second][Half-Minecraft day]) for a chicken to lay an egg.